# Why doesn't the php array convert to JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am reading data from the mysql database and i am saving them into an array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aargau
    [1] => appenzell_au
    [2] => appenzell_in
    [3] => basel-land
    [4] => basel-stadt
    [5] => bern
    [6] => freiburg
    [7] => genf
    [8] => glarus
    [9] => graub�nden
    [10] => jura
    [11] => luzern
    [12] => neuenburg
    [13] => nidwalden
    [14] => obwalden
    [15] => obwalden
    [16] => schwyz
    [17] => solothurn
    [18] => st_gallen
    [19] => tessin
    [20] => thurgau
    [21] => uri
    [22] => waadt
    [23] => wallis
    [24] => zug
    [25] => z�rich
)
```

THE CODE (client.class.php) THAT DOES THIS LOOKS LIKE THIS :

```
public function getCantons($country){
        $cantonsArray= array();
    //  $tmpArray = array();
        $sql_get_cantons = sprintf("SELECT name FROM locations WHERE country='".$country."'");
        $result = $this->CONNECTION->query($sql_get_cantons);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
            array_push($cantonsArray,$row['name']);
        }
        return $cantonsArray;
    }
```

I HAVE AN OTHER PHP FILE (server.php) which returns the answer to the ajax call

```
if($_POST['command']=='cantons'){
        $country = $_POST['country'];
        $client = new Client();
       // $results = $client->getActiveItemsOfCategory('technology');
        $results = $client->getCantons($country);
        $jsonResults = json_encode($results);
        print_r($jsonResults);
    }
```

IN THE AJAX CALL (which is working properly becauseI use I use the same code as in other AJAX calls) I simply do this :

```
 var jqxhr = $.post( "php/server.php", {country:COUNTRY,command:'cantons'},function() {

})
  .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
   })
  .fail(function(data) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  })
  .always(function() {

});
```

THE result is empty

Comment: It can't possibly work when you send it without encoding.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: edit your post to show exactly how you are doing your json_encode on the php side and show how you are sending/catching the AJAX request on the client side.

Comment: Do you echo the result `echo $resultsToJSON;`?

Comment: I do try it with print_r($jsonResults) and also echo $jsonResults but I get nothing

Comment: @JayBlanchard : Yes I have watched the request/response in the browser's console and i get 200 OK

Comment: Have you tried to make a request with a REST client, e.g. Postman for Chrome, to see if you get anything returned at all? That code runs fine in my environment, given that the array returned is correct. (I have not attached a DB when testing)

Comment: @ Jimmy Bernljung It appears that there is error in the data retrieved in database but that's weird because I use exactly the same code to retrieve other data from my database. When i write a random string (e.g. 'name') in the $row['name'] I do get the JSON correctly. 
I tried to convert the $row['name'] into string by $canton_name = strval($row['name']); but it doesn't work.

Comment: HELLO again guys! I figured out my error . It was in the encoding. Since I use German letters. I fixed it! Thanks everyone for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your server.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $jsonResults;
```

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work. It only shows the message : readyState =4 ....etc.. 
The weird thing is that in my server.php I have all my code in this fashion . Making ajax calls and returning data in json but the same method doesn't seem to work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` instead of `print_r` to output your JSON string

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the encoding of the letters. Apparently, I am using German alphabet that was the reason for this error.